# Tile doesn't update when no internet connection after upgrading to WP8 project

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile

I upgraded my Windows Phone project to WP8 project, now the tile doesn't update when no internet connection; after I connect to internet with 3G or Wifi, the tile will be updated.
My tile update doesn't need to connect to internet, and this function works in WP7 project before, it happens after I upgrade the project to WP8 project.

Comment: Please add some details about what tests you have already done to troubleshoot this problem. For example, if the tile is updated by a background agent, have you determined whetherthe agent is running?  If it is not running, have you looked for errors when the foreground app invokes ScheduledActionService?  If the agent *is* running, have you looked for unexpected errors or exceptions in that process?

Comment: Update: I find that this is not a problem of my app, I pinned several apps to start screen, all of them do not update until I connect to internet (3G or Wifi). I am running with GDR3 and Lumia Black update.

Comment: Would still like to hear more detail.  What do you mean "does not update"? That flip or cycle tiles don't flip or cycle? or that tiles with a count don't count up?  Can you make this happen with the tile of one of the standard apps?
After all, if the phone doesn't have internet connectivity, most apps will not receive new data to update the tile with, though a custom app might be written to update the tile.